# How to make the content in dropdown menu looks neat after bind with two column value from database?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I combined full name and last name in a query to form full name.
Here is my sql which works for this matter:

```
SELECT l_name|| ' ' ||f_name AS student_info FROM studentdb;
```

How to make space after the longest l_name so it shows two neat columns in dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

> fill one or more columns fill in your dropdownbox

You can apply this code according your info and and requirement, it's very easy to implement

```
sql = "select " + displaycol + ", " + valcol + " from " + tblName+ " WHERE " + where + " order by " + displaycol;
SqlCommand ObjCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, ObjConnection);

SqlDataAdapter ObjAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(ObjCommand);
ObjConnection.Open();
ObjAdapter.Fill(DT);
ObjConnection.Close();
ObjCommand.Dispose();
ObjAdapter.Dispose();

cmb.Enabled = false;
cmb.DataTextField = displaycol;
cmb.DataValueField = valcol;
cmb.DataSource = DT;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit of a hack, but maybe something like this:

```
select
    rpad (l_name, max (length (l_name)) over (partition by 1)) || ' ' || 
    f_name
from studentdb
```

Sample output:

```
James          Lebron
Gaffigan       Jim
Schwarzenegger Arnold
```

You probably need to do something with your font to ensure this shows up as fixed-width.

There is probably a better solution using `format`.

-- EDIT 9/3/2019 --

A C# approach to the same, assuming you have:

```
class Student
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Something like this would also work:

```
int maxLen = students.Select(x => x.LastName.Length).Max() + 1;
students.ForEach(x => x.LastName = x.LastName.PadRight(maxLen));
```

Comment: Thanks @Hambone,  what does the over (partition by 1) for?

Comment: That was just a hack to get the max over all records (partition by 1 = partition by a fixed value, meaning every row will be considered).  By the way, I added a C# way to do it, if you were so interested